# create lines by number of items django templates

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, django-templates

what i'm trying to do is:

create a

```
<div class="row-fluid center">
```

and just put max of 3 elements from list.dias.all
I'm having trouble to think os this code.

```
    <div class="row-fluid center" id="{{list.dias.all.count}}">
    {% for dia in list.dias.all %}  
            <div class="span4" id="element" >
                <div>
                    <h6 style="color: #9937d8">{{dia.tipo_dias.description}}</h6>
                    <small style="color: #b2e300">{{ dia.title_yt }}</small>

                </div>  
                <div id="another div"></div>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}    
    </div>
```

Is kind of newbie question, but I don't know if is better to solve using Django, django-templates or jQuery.

Thanks in advance

--
edited

Thanks! But I'm wanna iterate, for each three elements, create a new row.
I'm closer to answer right now.

If a list has 30 elements, create a row for each 3 elements. Not the first 3 ones.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it like that:

```
{% for dia in list.dias.all|slice:":3" %}
```

Comment: Thanks schacki, but I was misunderstood.

What I'm really want is:

If a list has 30 elements, create a row for each 3 elements.
Not the first ones.

But I'm closer right now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The 'cycle' template tag might be able to do what you want. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#cycle

I'm not certain which divs to open and close where for your examples, but the idea is you use the cycle tag to close and reopen the div every so many times through the loop, except when it's the last iteration.

```
<div class="row-fluid center" id="{{list.dias.all.count}}">
{% for dia in list.dias.all %}  
    <div class="span4" id="element" >
        <div>
            <h6 style="color: #9937d8">{{dia.tipo_dias.description}}</h6>
            <small style="color: #b2e300">{{ dia.title_yt }}</small>
         </div>
    {% if forloop.revcounter > 1 %}{% cycle '' '' '</div><div>' %}{% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}    
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is certainly not exactly right. Like I said I'm not certain which div is which. And the loop tags probably aren't in the right place for this to work either. If I could see what the end result is supposed to look like, I may be able to improve this answer.